# Angular 2 append input element on keypress

Tags: angular

What is the best way to append DOM element (input in my case) in Angular 2?

Do I have to use ComponentFactoryResolver or there is easier way for these simple things?

I need this - when user type something in input, to append same input below(just once, on first typed letter).

After that, i need same append functionality but just on last input and so on...
Something like when you want to type more attributes for example I make it easier for you by adding you one more filed...

Here is example solved with JQuery:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".addanother", function ()
{   
    $(".inputList").append('<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col-lg-5\"><input type="text" placeholder="Attribute" class="form-control addanother" /></div>' +
                                                '<div class=\"col-lg-5\"><input type="text" placeholder="Value" class="form-control"/></div></div>');
    $(this).removeClass("addanother");
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a `FormArray` created with `FormBuilder` and `*ngFor`. Read the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should look at the documentation. However a first approach might be something like this:

HTML:

```
<button (keypress)="addAnother()">add</button>
<div *ngFor="let form of formdivs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Attribute" class="form-control addanother" /></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5"><input type="text" placeholder="Value" class="form-control" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then, in the controller:

```
 public formdivs: any[] = [];

  addAnother(): void {
    this.formdivs.push({});//Add info for new div if needed
  }
```

Hope that helps as a starting point. 
The part of the css might be placed in the button like this:

```
[ngClass]="{'addAnother': formdivs.length == 0}"
```